# select and deselect parameters as output to JSON ,depending up on the incoming request in java

Tags: java

For example I have an incoming request with URL: "/cid/{cid}/{action}"

For path variable {action} I can have two values i.e.  {action}: **1)list  2)tile**

My POJO class with parameters for JSON output is below:

```java
public class Area {

    private Integer aId;
    private String aName;
    private Integer allSpaces;
    private Integer violated;
    private Integer percent;
    private Integer level;
    private List<Space> space = new ArrayList<Space>(); // this List should be depend on condition

    public Area(Integer aId, String aName, Integer allSpaces, Integer violated, Integer percent, Integer level) {
        this.aId = aId;
        this.aName = aName;
        this.allSpaces = allSpaces;
        this.level = level;
        this.violated = violated;
        this.percent = percent;
    }

    public Integer getaId() {
        return aId;
    }

    public void setaId(Integer aId) {
        this.aId = aId;
    }

    public String getaName() {
        return aName;
    }

    public void setaName(String aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }

    public Area addSpace(Space s) {
        space.add(s);

        return this;
    }

    public List<Space> getSpace() {
        return space;
    }

    public void setSpace(List<Space> space) {
        this.space = space;
    }

    public Integer getAllSpaces() {
        return allSpaces;
    }

    public void setAllSpaces(Integer allSpaces) {
        this.allSpaces = allSpaces;
    }

    public Integer getViolated() {
        return violated;
    }

    public void setViolated(Integer violated) {
        this.violated = violated;
    }

    public Integer getPercent() {
        return percent;
    }

    public void setPercent(Integer percent) {
        this.percent = percent;
    }

    public Integer getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(Integer level) {
        this.level = level;
    }
}
```

My output should not consist the parameter `private List space = new ArrayList()` for *action =list* but show it for *action=tile*.

It will of great help if any body can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

If the class gets serialized, and you want to exclude `space` from serialization to JSON, you can mark it as `transient`.

```
private transient List<Space> space = new ArrayList<Space>();
```

In the case where you would like to decide if this happens or not, you can subclass `Area`
So your controller would either invoke `ListArea` or `TileArea`.

Comment: sorry even if i make it private transient List<Space> space = new ArrayList<Space>(); it is still included in the serialization but if i annotate the property with  @JsonIgnore
    public List<Space> getSpace() {
        return space;       it is excluded from the serialization but if i do so it will not be reusable again.so is there any other approch
    }

Comment: @user1642947, leave the list out in the area implementation, and rather use it in your subclassed classes as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for my question

I intialized `private List<Space> space = null;` instead of `private List<Space> space = new ArrayList<Space>();`

and added **@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)** on top of my pojo like below

**@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class Area {**

now the parameters whose `value==null` will not be included in the serialized output, but I can intialize it dynamically by using constructur and retrive to output if required.